# What is the optimal way to access a thread-specific index?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, memory, thread-local-storage

In my program I create `n` threads. Each thread starts with the same "main thread function". That function is given a unique `thread_index` by the code, which spawns the threads:

```cpp
void worker_main_func(int thread_index);

vector<thread> spawn_workers(int n) {
    vector<thread> workers;
    workers.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        workers.emplace_back(worker_main_func, i);
    }
    return workers;
}
```

Each worker thread needs access to a dedicated queue. They are all allocated up front. To access its queue, a thread needs to know its `thread_index`:

```cpp
static vector<my_queue_t> g_queues;

void do_some_work();

void worker_main_func(int thread_index) {
   do_some_work();
}
```

```cpp
void do_some_work {
  // ...
  g_queues[get_this_thread_index_somehow()].some_operation_on_queue();
  // ...
}
```

I can't really pass the `thread_index` to `do_some_work` as that would require changing nearly the entire codebase. Every function would need to take an additional parameter. For functions which currently pass their arguments through registers, this could incur a performance penalty. With a new parameter, they could potentially need to pass their arguments on the stack instead.

```cpp
void do_some_work(int thread_index);
void calculate(int thread_index, /* params */);
void fetch_data(int thread_index, /* params */);
void implementation1(int thread_index, /* params */);
void blablabla(int thread_index, /* params */);
```

As such, I store the `thread_index` in a `thread_local` variable and read it every time:

```cpp
thread_local int g_thread_index;

void worker_main_func(int thread_index) {
   g_thread_index = thread_index;
   do_some_work();
}
```

```cpp
void do_some_work {
  // ...
  g_queues[g_thread_index].some_operation_on_queue();
  // ...
}
```

It works, but this approach is suboptimal. That's because the compiler generates code which fetches the `g_thread_index` from memory (or cache), every time it is used and sometimes puts additional initialisation guards around it. At the same time, it is guaranteed, that all work that a thread does is contained in the `worker_main_func`. This means, that `worker_main_func` along with its parameters is always available - at the bottom of the stack:

```
--- inner_most_call ----
  ...
  param2
  param1
--- fetch_data ---------
  param3
  param2
  param1
--- calculate1 ---------
--- do_some_work -------
  thread_index
--- worker_main_func ---
```

So instead of reading the `thread_index` from memory, the compiler could simply read it from a fixed offset, relative to the current thread's stack.

I considered using `std::this_thread::get_id()` instead of my own `thread_index`, but that generates calls to `pthread_self` and would require some mapping to get a `[0..n)` index from an opaque `thread::id`.

Comment: "I can't really pass the thread_index to do_some_work as that would require changing nearly the entire codebase. Every function would need to take an additional parameter" - there are tools that can assist with large scale refactorings like that.

Comment: use std::async + a lambda that will capture your thread index. The std::future returned is a good way to get values + errors back from your workerthreads

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks, for the suggestion. Still, updating the codebase isn't a problem only because of the changes being large-scale. I also worry that adding an additional parameter to all functions could make some of them slower. For example, a function which currently accepts its parameters through registers, could need to use the stack instead, if it had an additional parameter.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I considered using a lambda capture, but I don't know how it could help here. How would the functions deep in the call stack access the lambda object?

Comment: I hope my example helps, it is more the other way around. You can pass information into the lambda which can then be picked up by the thread. If you are not sure use value semantics, if you are sure the things you need in your thread live longer then your thread then you can consider capturing data by reference.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Passing data to the thread is not an issue. The issue is passing data between the main function on a thread and its callees (and the callees' callees and so on...).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a threading question. Ultimately you want a way to pass a local variable through a callstack without using function arguments for that, without using a global (`thread_local` here) state. The thread part is a distraction. This is a question as old as C. The common wisdom is to just use arguments.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux After reading your comment, I completely agree. Indeed, everything thread-related could be cut out. Thanks for this insight.

Comment: Maybe there is a duplicate for this on the site. This seems to be called _tramp data_.

Comment: Regarding your idea about the thread index being at a fix offset, this requires each function to known where in the callstack it will be. Otherwise you need to communicate an information (like a pointer) between functions and you're back to the original problem. This implies the eventual state of the callstack to be statically deterministic when that index is read. C++ does not have a way to express this. If this solution is applicable to you, it will likely at a minimum require inline assembly with all the complications that entails.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it using std::async.
Live demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/Z2-syPOJW

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// using namespace std; <== dont do this.

// ideally this should be in a class
thread_local int thread_index{ 0ul };

void some_existing_function()
{
    // sleep (not recommended) to cleanup output a bit
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    std::cout << "some_existing_function : " << thread_index << "\n";
    
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::future<int>> results(8ul); // we want 8 parallel actions
    int count{ 0ul };

    for (auto& result : results)
    {
        // start asynchronous functions and store their std::future objects.
        // this will spawn underlying threads for you (all in all std::async is just a nice abstraction)
        result = std::async(std::launch::async, [index = count++]
            {
                thread_index = index;
                some_existing_function();   
                return 40 + index;
            });
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));

    for (auto& result : results)
    {
        // result.get() will block until background thread has done the work.
        std::cout << result.get() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't solve my issue. Now, the `thread_index` is a lambda capture, instead of being a function parameter. But it is still not accessible by functions deep in the call stack of a thread.

Comment: Oh you mean you can't pass it onto functions because that means the signatures of existing functions would change?

Comment: Yes. Suppose I launch a thread like `async(launch::async, [index = ++I] { f() }`. Suppose that `f()` calls `g()` and `g()` calls `h()` and so on until `z()`. The function `z()` needs to somehow have access to the thread index, but it can't take it as a parameter. It can't because it already exists and I cannot change its signature.

Comment: Small update, you can store the index in a thread local variable, so z() can pick it up later.
It is a kind of workaround for not being able to change signatures. But that would imply you could change the implementation of z(). (I am not proud of using sleeps/globals here, they're there to help show the ideas not final implemantation)

Comment: Right now I am already storing the thread index in a `thread_local` variable. This is what the question is about: How do I solve this problem _without_ storing the index in a `thread_local` variable.

Comment: O sorry missed that bit, apologies for taking up your time.